# Play bytes as audio in ASP.NET MVC with custom bitrate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, audio, wav

I have an array of bytes with fixed length of 10,000 bytes. How can I convert this data into audio and then play it in view?

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work. I think it's because my data bitrate is custom as 160,000 bits per second. Regarding to my data (80,000 bits) audio should play about half second.

In my controller:

```
public FileStreamResult Audio()
{
      byte[] data;
      // fill data
      var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer: data, writable: false);
      return new FileStreamResult(stream, "audio/wav");
}
```

And in view I do:

```
<audio controls preload='none'>
      <source src='/MyController/Audio/' type='audio/wav'>
</audio>
```

Comment: What does `data` contain? Does it contain a valid WAV file? The audio is played by the *browser*. If the browser can't handle that content, you'll have to convert it to something that's understandable, or specify a codec that can actually understand the data. That assumes the coded is installed in the first place. Using custom formats just begs for trouble.

Comment: In any case, raw audio in WAV [isn't commonly used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs) because it's the largest possible size, completely unsuitable for web streaming. Never mind missed packets or error correction - it has none.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for your comments. `data` is an array of bytes that have been captured from digital microphone previously. When I attempt to play these bytes using `sounddevice` package in Python3 it plays very well. So if I don't use wav format, what should I? Would you please help me?